# Deployment - Picklist - Opportunity Contact Role

Tags: apex, sales

I am trying to deploy a picklist item on Opportunity Contact Role, as you can see as follows:

[image]
I cannot find that item in "Component Type" list.

How can I add that picklist item to the outbound change set?

Comment: see https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=0 for allowed metadata types; @sfdcneuf has the answer. Frankly, for something this simple, you can just make the change directly in both sandbox and prod if you are allowed and don't want to learn force.com migration tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, standard field picklist values cannot be migrated using change sets:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000HJ3kAAG

One possible alternative is to use the Force.com migration tool - standard picklists are accessible under the StandardValueSet metadata type:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm